# Fake reverse relationship for django model

Tags: django, orm, reverse, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following code:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    pass

class Shipment(models.Model):
    tx = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    sub = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)


class Subscription(models.Model):
    pass
```

I'm trying make a reverse relation between Subscription and Transaction like this:

```
subscription.transaction_set.all()
```

The only way I can come up with is to use a fake property like this:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):

    @property
    def transaction_set(self):
        return Transaction.objects.filter(
            pk__in=[s.tx.pk for s in self.shipment_set.all()]
        )
```

But now I have come against an admin problem. I would like to list the transactions using admin.TabularInline in the admin site. This is where my solution breaks down. Does anyone have any idea?

I also need to list the shipments using admin.TabularInline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are looking form [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) argument:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    pass

class Subscription(models.Model):
    transactions = models.ManyToManyField(Transaction, through='Shipment')

class Shipment(models.Model):
    tx = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    sub = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)
```

Then:

```
subscription.transactions.all()
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I think because in my head I'd already structured it and i didn't realise that the shipment model was already acting like a through model. Thanks.

Comment: I think I may have accepted this answer in haste. The relationship works but I'm getting the following error: <class 'admin.TransactionInline'>: (admin.E202) 'sagepay.Transaction' has no ForeignKey to 'subscription.Subscription'. Which is the same error I was getting before.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this only lists the intermediary models i.e. the Shipments. I need to list both the shipments and the transactions in tabular form. Any more ideas? I feel like we're almost there.

Comment: Okay, I found a workaround using your solutions. I've added verbose_name = 'Transaction' to my admin.TabularInline and made all of the fields methods that return the related object attributes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The merit is yours. Congrats.